# EntityManager's named query are slow where as JPAEntityManager's Expression query are faster

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I am using Weblogic 10.3 and EJB3 with TopLinks(EclipseLinks) JPA implementation. I am facing an issue with my named queries, which are performing slow. However If I use EclipseLinks JPAEntityManager's Expression query to achieve same, its faster. I am not able to understand why my standard JPA named queries are slow. Has anyone faced similiar issue or Can someone explain the root cause of this issue.

Am I missing any basic tunning or parameter???

Comment: I think you are missing a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd.  Named queries should be in general faster as they are parsed once.

What is the specific query and its SQL?  Are you comparing it to the same Expression query, or something different, which is its SQL?

Try enabling the EclipseLink PerformanceProfiler on the queries, or try using a Java profiler such as JProfiler.